# Function of MOSFET based circuit

Tags: mosfet, resistors, network

I am curious to find out the functionality and working of below circuit.
[image]
￼

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This circuit basically operates as a switch, allowing current to flow through \$Q_1\$ depending on the state of \$Q_2\$.

I assume that you have some logic driving the gate of the mosfet \$Q_2\$, by either pulling it to ground (turning it off), or pulling it high via resistor \$R_1\$.

If the gate of \$Q_2\$ is high, it is ON, meaning that the gate of \$Q_1\$ is pulled to ground via \$R_3\$, which in turn turns it (\$Q_1\$) ON as its \$V_{GS} < V_{TH}\$.

If the gate of \$Q_2\$ is low, it is OFF, meaning that the gate of \$Q_1\$ is pulled to its \$V_S\$ via \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$, which in turn turns it (\$Q_1\$) OFF as its \$V_{GS} > V_{TH}\$.

Sometimes it is necessary to turn off/on the inline MOSFET \$Q_1\$ a bit more slowly, (e.g. to improve EMC). However, it comes with the burden of increasing the power dissipation of the transistor since it operates longer in the linear region (large \$R_{ds,on}\$). This slower switching is achieved by adding the gate resistor \$R_3\$ which slows down the charging and discharing of the \$Q_1\$'s gate capacitance.

The resistor \$R_2\$ is necessary to limit the current through \$Q_2\$ when it is ON.

The \$C_1\$ adds some filtering to the \$V_{GS}\$ of \$Q_1\$, attenuating high spikes from the supply / source voltage. Furthermore, it also slows down even more the turning on/off time of the MOSFET (\$Q_1\$).

Comment: Why are R2 and R3 both needed and what is the roll of C1? It seems like R3 could be replaced with a short, and C1 could be removed and the logic would be unchanged.

Comment: @mkeith Answer updated.

Comment: My take on it is that C1 is there to make sure Q1 does not turn on too quickly when power is first applied. But maybe it is just filtering. Anyway good answer.